# C# serial command to move Arduino servo X degrees?

Tags: c#, serial-port, arduino

I have an Arduino wired up with a servo (Pin 9, 5.5v and Ground), it will run with any ol' testing on the Arduino; however, when I send a serial command to move it, well nothing happens. The rx light flashes so I know the Arduino is getting the info. I think the issue is in my byte conversion.

Code Time:

Arduino Code:

```
#include <Servo.h> 

Servo myservo;  // create servo object to control a servo 
                // a maximum of eight servo objects can be created 
void setup() 
{ 
    myservo.attach(9); 
    // attaches the servo on pin 9 to the servo object and sets the rotation to 0
    myservo.write(0); 
} 

int pos1= 0;
int pos2= 0;
int pos3= 0;
int totalMove = 0;

void loop() 
{ 
    if (Serial.available() > 0 && totalMove > 0)
    {
        pos1 = Serial.read() - '0'; 
        // pos2 = Serial.read() - '0'; 
        // pos3 = Serial.read() - '0'; 
        // totalMove = ((pos3) + (pos2*10) + pos1*100);

        myservo.write(pos1);
     }
}
```

You see the other pos holders because evenutally I would like to be able to send values larger than 9, however for now I just need to get it to respond :)

C# code:

```
public void moveServo()
{
    if (!serialPort1.IsOpen)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Oops");
        serialPort1.Open();
        return;
    }

    serialPort1.DtrEnable = true;

    serialPort1.DataReceived += 
        new System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(
            serialPort1_DataReceived);

    serialPort1.Write(new byte[] {57}, 0, 1);
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: http://arduino.cc/playground/Learning/SingleServoExample

Comment: How are you instantiating and initializing the `serialPort1` object in the C# code?

Comment: serialPort1 = new System.IO.Ports.SerialPort(components);
            serialPort1.PortName = "COM4";
            serialPort1.BaudRate = 9600;
            serialPort1.Open();
Like that

Comment: @Hans Passant Thank you! I picked through the code and this seems like it will work! Will test it out when I get home, if you want you can put this into an answer and I can accept it!

Comment: It is just link soup.  Post the code you ended up using in your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you made sure it works using other software?  That's typically the first step, even if you have to use hyperterminal.  That'll shake out any cable problems and give you the correct parameters.

Also I recommend [PortMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896644), from SysInternals.  It lets you monitor serial port activity while your application runs.

Make sure you're setting all the serial port parameters; baud rate, data bits, stop bits, parity, handshake, and read and write timeout.  You can also set the value to use for a NewLine character.

Also, rather than relying on the data recieved event, you might try reading it yourself.

Comment: Thanks; however, the connection is being made fine and the board is receiving the data (The RX light flashes at a 1 second interval set up by the C# app) so that is not the issue. Im pretty sure the issue lies in the byte conversion from int ---> Byte ---> int, I just cant figure out where things went ary...

Answer (score 1):

You are sending this byte

```
serialPort1.Write(new byte[] {57}, 0, 1);
```

which basically is the character `'9'`. The receiver code is

```
pos1 = Serial.read() - '0';
```

which means that `pos1` has the value `9` (note the missing `'`). This value is then written directly to the `Servo` instance.

```
myservo.write(pos1);
```

Summing together all parts: You can effectively send only the values 0 to 9 to the servo. But the [reference page](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/ServoWrite) tells you that `write` requires the range 0 to 180. Sending only 0 to 9 to the servo might just wiggle it a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

maybe it's because of your logic level.

the lpt and serial port output is 2.5v and some driver's need 5v to set and reset.

so you need an ic like max232 to convert logic level from 2.5v to 5volt.